# return by reference or pointer and check for null?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, protocol-buffers

```
I have a class :

class A
{
  private:
    vector<int> x;
  public:
     const vector<int>& immutable_data() {
         return x;
      }
      vector<int>* mutable_data() {
          return &x;
      }
}
```

Now if i use this class , in my code , do i have to check if the pointer returned by the mutable_data() is null or not (given that i know the structure of this class). Personally i think i don't have to because i know there exist a secondary api which returns a const reference and so my pointer can never be null (I can't imagine of a scenario where this function would return me null ,even if it somehow does returns null, what would be the behavior of the const ref version in that case). Or should i say that i know its an address of an existing object on stack , so it cannot be null ? Is this the correct way to think or reason about this ? If any one thinks the other way , please give some example code.

For a more common case scenario in production code : if i use protocol buffers , i already know the generated code for my message templates (for eg: repeatedfields which are like stl containers), but do i still need to do null check every time i want to use the mutable api because they always return either by pointer or const reference.

returning by reference is not what i am looking for.

Comment: Its your code, so it's your choice! Remember that if the method is virtual then all subclasses need to stick to the contract else you'll hit problems.

Comment: Is there a problem with `const vector<int> &data() const` and `vector<int> &data()`?

Comment: Remember: if you're object of `A` is fully-constructed, then `A::x` too is fully constructed. `x` cannot become `NULL`, as it is not stored somewhere else and accessed indirectly using a pointer (and not a reference, for a reference cannot become `NULL`).

Comment: In general, you need to make sure pointers are not null before you indirect them.  Once you know it isn't null, you can keep a reference to the object it points to to make it clear that no more checking is necessary.

Comment: @chris : I wanted to focus more on the case where checking of null for pointers is redundant.

Comment: i understand the usual scenario of using pointers , but i am trying to clean up and refactor some code and where the stye usage forces me to use only const references else pointers as api interfaces. So I wanted to make sure if somehow i can guarantee that pointers will not be null in cases like above, will save a lot of redundant null checks

Answer (score 1):

> do i have to check if the pointer returned by the mutable_data() is null or not (given that i know the structure of this class)

In general, design elements like "have to check the pointer" depends on one of two things:

1. Does your design need to be provably safe?
2. If not, then does the design of `A::mutable_data()` dictate that it won't return `null`?

If (1), then you should invest in the kind of SAT-solver based tools which can test statically that your code won't access invalid memory.

If (2), I recommend that you consider the concept of Design by Contract -- it is a powerful one.  If `A::mutable_data()`'s interface is specified not to return `null`, then it returning `null` would be a design defect in `A::mutable_data()`.

Comment: In the last paragraph, if the interface is specified to not return a null pointer, then returning a null pointer would be a coding error, not a design defect.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a null pointer usually means "I don't have any data for you". If the class will always have data, then, by design, the function will never return a null pointer. If that's the case, then code that uses the function does not need to check for null pointers. That's one of the guarantees that the function makes: "I won't ever return a null pointer".